# Assistance with decoding obfuscated code

Tags: discussion

I have stumbled across [a simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66326289/how-do-i-do-the-base64-in-my-python-file), where the user has claimed to have encoded their script in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and does not know how to revert back to the original to make changes.

The task at hand is quite simple, where one may assume the original creator of the code would be able to reverse engineer it themselves and regain the source.

The encoded source file, also further obfuscates the code by changing imports to random two-letter variables.

```
nd=open
nf=str
nS=print
nk=locals
```

The user account is new, and has asked a question relating to [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)) bots previously, which is somewhat relevant as the decoded source is a Discord bot, although it is a little different.

---

Given the above, I'm unsure if answering the question is the right course of action. I also was looking to vote for closure. However, I am unsure on which closure reason would be relevant to this question.

I noted there is one close-to-vote option specifying that the question needs more details or clarity. However, the question can be answered with the information provided.

What would be the best course of action for handling this question?

Comment: When you type "decode base64" into google, the first hit is (likely) a site which can encode and decode base64. That literally takes seconds to do, while asking a question and waiting for answers takes a whole lot longer. It is pretty much a poster example of "No research, not useful", so downvoting is step one. But it also leaves me baffled that the OP wouldn't do this incredibly simple step themselves so there must be more to it for this to not be an act of extreme lethargy - assuming the best there that there is more to it. So that brings us to "needs more details".

Comment: As a rule of thumb, be wary of any "mcve" that feeds obfuscated code to ``eval``. There is no shame in simply ignoring obscure questions.

Comment: @Gimby the code can only partially be decoded like that. The OP went further to obfuscate part of the code with `rot13` so a simple bsase64 decode only actually decoded half of the source. @MisterMiyagi yeah I was originally concerned by the code, as if it was a malicious intent to have SO posters run the eval and cause harm. This is why i decoded it without eval to double check that it wasnt malicious. I was more concerned that OP didnt own the code and wanted someone to RE it for them.

Comment: Also, could somebody with the privilege to see deleted posts put the content of the now-deleted question here in a comment? I'd like to edit it into my answer.

Comment: I don't have access to see deleted things, but I still have a copy floating on my hard drive from taking a stab at REing it (it looked harmless to me, but given it was obfuscated even when decoded, I realized it's not worth the time).  Here's a [truncated view](https://pastebin.com/fwa2UVcX) of what it was, I commented out the evals and truncated the strings (and fun fact, the full version triggers pastebin's spam detection).  Here's a [truncated dump](https://pastebin.com/yb9xe63V) of what it decodes to.  Looked to be a discord bot for a homework site of some sort.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 It's too big to fit in a comment, but I edited it into your post, so you can adjust it from there.

Comment: I don't believe that poster did anything with the code but post the question, sorry - they didn't author it nor "lose" the sources. It was a nicely executed ruse. Nuke it from orbit and move on, nice try on the poster's end, but let's not be naive. If you know enough to write that stuff once, you know enough to write it again, and anyone sane should be using some version control anyway, discord bot or no bot. It's basically a script kiddie sort of a question that should never be encouraged.

Comment: I actually replaced the eval and compile functions with a custom function that just outputted any input, and ran it. It seems to actually be part of a valid Discord bot, leading me to think he just stole it from a Git repo.

Comment: Turns out, you can find similar code all over `github`. The obfuscation seems to have been done on a website where you simply upload your code, and it returns the same exact file format and variable names seen in OP's post. It seems the OP may have obfuscated his code using this site with no knowledge of how to revert it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Personally, I think either a downvote or a flag for "Needs details and clarity" would be warranted here.

The post doesn't give many details about what kind of script the OP coded, or how exactly the OP tried to solve the issue, or what all the cryptic variable names mean. It makes this question pretty tough to answer; certainly not impossible, but you'd have to assume a lot of details.

EDIT: I flagged the post and it has now been closed and deleted. Case in point.

Thanks to user513951 for helping me get the original contents of the post. Take a look at this abomination:

> **How do I do the base64 in my python file?**
>
> I encoded my script at one point, but forgot to save the original :) Now, I want to make an edit, but can't get it decoded. I would much appreciate anyone who could help :)
>
> ```
> import base64, codecs
> magic = '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'
> love = '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'
> god = 'bHAvIiBub3QgaW4gaSk6CiAgIHJldHVybi0xCiAgZWxzZToKICAgTj1hd2FpdCBZKGkpCiBlbHNlOgogIEE9bC5nZXQoaSxoZWFkZXJzPXopCiAgaD1CZWF1dGlmdWxTb3VwKEEudGV4dCwiaHRtbC5wYXJzZXIiKQogIE49bmYoaC5maW5kKCJkaXYiLHsiY2xhc3MiOiJhbnN3ZXItZ2l2ZW4tYm9keSB1Z2MtYmFzZSJ9KSkKICBmb3IgZCBpbiBoLmZpbmRfYWxsKCJsaSIpOgogICBpZiAnZGF0YS1hbnN3ZXJpZCcgaW4gZC5hdHRycy5rZXlzKCk6CiAgICBmPWQuYXR0cnNbJ2RhdGEtYW5zd2VyaWQnXQogICAgblMoZikKICAgIFM9KCgnZW50aXR5VHlwZScsJ0FOU1dFUicpLCgnZW50aXR5SWQnLGYpLCkKICAgIGs9bC5nZXQoJ2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNoZWdnLmNvbS9zdHVkeS9fYWpheC9jb250ZW50ZmVlZGJhY2svZ2V0cmV2aWV3JyxoZWFkZXJzPXoscGFyYW1zPVMpCiAgICBrPW5oKGsudGV4dCkKICAgIGs9a1sncmV2aWV3X2NvdW50J11bJ3Jlc3VsdCddCiAgICBpZiAnMCcgaW4gay5rZXlzKCk6CiAgICAgdz1rWycwJ11bJ2NvdW50J10KICAgIGlmICcxJyBpbiBrLmtleXMoKToKICAgICBNPWtbJzEnXVsnY291bnQnXQogICAgblMoaykKICAgIGJyZWFrCiAgTj1OLnJlcGxhY2UoJ3NyYz0iLy8nLCdzcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vJykKICBpZihOPT0iTm9uZSIpOgogICBOPW5mKGguZmluZCgiZGl2Iix7ImNsYXNzIjoiaGFuZ1RpZ2h0In0pKQogICBpZihOPT0iTm9uZSIpYW5kICI8dGl0bGU+R2V0IEhvbWV3b3JrIEhlbHAgV2l0aCBDaGVnZyBTdHVkeSB8IENoZWdnLmNvbTwvdGl0bGU+IiBub3QgaW4gQS50ZXh0OgogICAgYz1BLnRleHRbQS50ZXh0LmZpbmQoInBhZ2VOYW1lRGV0YWlsZWQiKTpdCiAgICBjPWMuc3BsaXQoJyInKVsyXQogICAgcj1bbS5zdGFydCgpZm9yIG0gaW4gbmUoJ3Rva2VuJyxBLnRleHQpXQogICAgdT1BLnRleHRbclswXTpdLnNwbGl0KCciJylbMl0KICAgIFM9KCgndG9rZW4nLHUpLCgncXVlc3Rpb25VdWlkJyxjKSwoJ3Nob3dPbmJvYXJkaW5nJywnJyksKCd0ZW1wbGF0ZU5hbWUnLCdFTkhBTkNFRF9DT05URU5UX1YxJyksKSAKICAgIEU9bC5nZXQoJ2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNoZWdnLmNvbS9zdHVkeS9fYWpheC9lbmhhbmNlZGNvbnRlbnQnLGhlYWRlcnM9eixwYXJhbXM9UykKICAgIFE9KEUudGV4dC5yZXBsYWNlKCJcbiIsIiIpKQogICAgUT1RLnJlcGxhY2UoIlxcIiwiIikKICAgIFE9US5yZXBsYWNlKCI+biIsIj4iKQogICAgUT1RLnJlcGxhY2UoIjwvZGl2Pm4iLCI8L2Rpdj4iKQogICAgUT1RLnJlcGxhY2UoIi0tPm4iLCItLT4iKQogICAgaD1CZWF1dGlmdWxTb3VwKFEsImh0bWwucGFyc2VyIikKICAgIE49bmYoaC5maW5kKCJzZWN0aW9uIix7ImlkIjoic3RlcHMifSkpCiAgIGVsc2U6CiAgICByZXR1cm4tMQogVD0iPGgxPiBMaWtlczogIit3KyIgPC9oMT4iIGlmICdsaWtlcycgaW4gbmsoKWVsc2UgIjxoMT4gTGlrZXM6IDAgPC9oMT4iCiBhPSI8aDE+IERpc2xpa2VzOiAiK00rIiA8L2gxPiIgaWYgJ2Rpc2xpa2VzJyBpbiBuaygpZWxzZSAiPGgxPiBEaXNsaWtlczogMCA8L2gxPiIKIE49VCthK04KIGY9bkgoTikKIGYudHJ1bmNhdGUoMTAwMDApCiB0cnk6CiAgZjI9bkUoTixudyxjb25maWc9eSkKICBCPW5nKGYyKQogZXhjZXB0OgogIEU9bmwoImh0dHBzOi8vZW5jcnlwdGVkLXRibjAuZ3N0YXRpYy5jb20v'
> destiny = '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'
> joy = '\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33'
> trust = eval('\x6d\x61\x67\x69\x63') + eval('\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x6c\x6f\x76\x65\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29') + eval('\x67\x6f\x64') + eval('\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x64\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6e\x79\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29')
> eval(compile(base64.b64decode(eval('\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74')),'<string>','exec'))
> ```

Also, take a look at [Anon Coward's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405461/assistance-with-decoding-obfuscated-code/405463#comment826675_405461) to see what this decodes to...